# Bug when implement "check point inside triangle" algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, collision-detection

I'm following the algorithm 1 in [this article](http://www.sunshine2k.de/stuff/Java/PointInTriangle/PointInTriangle.html) to check if a point is inside a triangle. This is my code:

```
//========================================================================================================================//
// Methods
//========================================================================================================================//

private float getPerpDotProduct(final PointF p1, final PointF p2) {
    return p1.x * p2.y - p1.y * p2.x;
}

private boolean isInside(final PointF pPoint) { 
    final float c1 = this.getPerpDotProduct(this.mA, pPoint);
    final float c2 = this.getPerpDotProduct(this.mB, pPoint);
    final float c3 = this.getPerpDotProduct(this.mC, pPoint);

    return ((c1 >= 0 && c2 >= 0 & c3 >= 0) || (c1 <= 0 && c2 <= 0 && c3 <= 0));
}
```

And this is my test:
[image]

Cyan zone: The real triangle I give.

Pink zone: "Inside" the triangle

Blue Zone: "Outside" the triangle

**EDIT:**

This is my new code to calculate by vectors:

```
private PointF getVector(final PointF pPoint1, final PointF pPoint2) {
    return new PointF(pPoint2.x - pPoint1.x, pPoint2.y - pPoint1.y);
}

private float getPerpDotProduct(final PointF p1, final PointF p2) {
    return p1.x * p2.y - p1.y * p2.x;
}

private boolean isInside(final PointF pPoint) { 
    final float c1 = this.getPerpDotProduct(getVector(this.mA, this.mB), getVector(this.mA, pPoint));
    final float c2 = this.getPerpDotProduct(getVector(this.mB, this.mC), getVector(this.mB, pPoint));
    final float c3 = this.getPerpDotProduct(getVector(this.mC, this.mA), getVector(this.mC, pPoint));

    return ((c1 > 0 && c2 > 0 & c3 > 0) || (c1 < 0 && c2 < 0 && c3 < 0));
}
```

Please clarify my code. Thank you.

Comment: Try replacing the >= with > and <= with < in your return statement as done in the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "bug" in the article's description of what needs to be done:

> Calculate the perpDotProduct/crossproduct of all three points V1, V2, V3 with the testpoint P

should be "Calculate the perpDotProduct/crossproduct of all three **vectors** with vectors to the testpoint P".

As explained in the article, the algorithm returns `true` if all three points are visible at the same "angular direction" from the origin (the upper-left corner of your picture). Your picture shows it precisely, too: vectors `(0, p)` for all pink points need to turn clockwise to reach the triangle if they are above the blue zone; if they are below the blue zone, the vectors would need to move counterclockwise.

To fix the algorithm, you need to compute cross products of vectors `{(V1-V2), (V1-P)}`, `{(V2-V3), (V2-P)}`, and `{(V3-V1), (V3-P)}`. Take a look at [this article](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) for pseudocode.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion, but now all the points are considered outside of the triangle. Did I do anything wrong? I have read the article you give before, but it's quite confusing. I don't know which type the `CrossProduct` and `DotProduct` functions in that article return or take. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistypo in my code, it works now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @W.N. No problem! I tested an implementation on ideone, and it worked. I guess you don't need it now, but [here it is anyway](http://ideone.com/5dH9A) :)

Answer (score 1):

I normally do the math like this, using barycentric coordinates:
(considering 4 points where p1,p2,p3 are the triangle and p4 is the point you want to check:
consider (p1,p3) as the vector p1 -> p3

```
dot00 = (p1,p3).(p1,p3)
dot01 = (p1,p3).(p1,p2)
dot02 = (p1,p3).(p1,p4)
dot11 = (p1,p2).(p1,p2)
dot12 = (p1,p2).(p1,p4)


inverseDenominator = (1 / (dot00*dot11 - dot01*dot01)

u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01*dot12) * inverseDenominator
v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01*dot02) * inverseDenominator
```

Now that we have the barycentric coordinates calculated, the verification is simple, should P4 lie inside the triangle (P1,P2,P3)$ then `u` and `v` must both be positive and summed up together they must be smaller than one:

```
u >= 0 && v >= 0 && u + v < 1
```

This is the article where I learned how to do it when I was doing my thesis: http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html
(you'll find similarities with the variable names :p)

Comment: Thank you. I also read this article before, but I have no idea how it works because I have never been taught about it. I also tried to implement this solution, and it works :) Thank you :)